# Only one beefalo?

Tags: dont-starve

I had a default game, and didn't change any settings in Don't Starve. I ran the entire map. I found all of the savannah's and searched every square inch of them. Sadly only one savannah had one lone beefalo.

What can I do to get more beefalo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you just have to guard that beefalo. You can build a fence around it if you wish. At some point, the lone beefalo will magically create a new baby beefalo. I'm not sure how many days this takes. From this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dontstarve/comments/2jg1sc/when_you_only_have_one_beefalo/) the thread poster replied to his own comment with a screenshot of their new baby beefalo. It didn't happen until day 39.

[image: BEEFALOOOOOO]

If you're ultra impatient, you can also use console commands.

> DebugSpawn("beefalo") - this will spawn one beefalo at your mouse pointer.
>
> c_spawn("beefalo", amount) - adding an integer for amount will spawn "amount" of beefalo.